# Enqueue script with url_query variables?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Is there an easy way to enqueue a JavaScript file with url_query values populated?

I have a php file underneath my js directory with JavaScript headers that I want to generate some dynamic JavaScript depending on the url_query values.

Thanks

Gs

UPDATE:

Yes, in the widget class I added the following (as a test):

(in the constructor, I just wanted to make a completely unique ID so I took the timestamp + a bunch of random #s):

```
$this->widget_id=time().rand(2,10).rand(2,10).rand(2,10).rand(2,10).rand(2,10).rand(2,10);
add_action('wp_footer', array( &$this, 'footer_js' ));
```

(then the method):

```
public function footer_js(){
      wp_register_script( 'mgs-site-script'.$this->widget_id, $this->plugin_location . "js/mgs.js", array('jquery'),'1.2.0');
      wp_enqueue_script( 'mgs-site-script'.$this->widget_id );
      $translation_array = array( 'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate' ), 'a_value' => '10' );
      wp_localize_script( 'mgs-site-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );
  }
```

Then in mgs.js I tried to access the variables by calling:

```
alert(object_name.some_string);
```

but firebug spits out "object_name is not defined"

Comment: have you tried using `wp_localize_script` ? Its a easy way to passing variables/values to javascript file. Not via url parameter though. It creates a global object.


  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: I tried it - but it didnt work, I updated the question w/ details

Comment: If you're not hooking the `wp_enqueue_script()` function to the `wp_enqueue_script` hook, you're asking for trouble. It comes with an $in_footer parameter which it seems you'd take advantage of.

Comment: Great call, that was oversight on my part.

Comment: HOWEVER... it seems that I cannot enqueue a script from the "Widget" method in a widget object, is that correct? Can't find anything online about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't get super specific without a more-detailed example from you, but I think you could combine [`get_query_var()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to do what you want like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sg_scripts' );
function sg_scripts() {

    $current_slug = get_query_var( 'page_name' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sg_custom_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/somefile.php?slug=' . $current_slug, $dependencies, $version, $in_footer);

}
```

(I left the last three arguments as placeholders.)

Admittedly I've never tried this. A few things that might give you trouble:

- I don't know what happens if `wp_enqueue_script()` is passed a non-.js file. It might get filtered out.
- I know that a lot of the caching plugins (and WordPress?) look to the $version arg for caching. If you're seeing an old version of the js from a recent slug get served, I imagine that's what's going on.

Alternately, this is much less dynamic, but you can wrap individual `wp_enqueue_script()` instances with static .js files in `if` statements that test the `query_var` e.g.:

```
$current_slug = get_query_var( 'page_name' );
if( $current_slug == 'something' ) {
    \\ enqueue a script
} elseif( $current_slug == 'somethingelse' ) {
    \\ enqueue a different script
}
} else {
    \\ enqueue a third script
}
```

Comment: If this answer answers your question, you should **accept it**, by clicking the **checkmark** beneath the answer up/down vote arrows.